Pandas table error while try to get col positions
this is example of my code - im using tkinter with tabs and pandas table inside.
when im trying to insert data to a cell in the first tab im getting error
`
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
 
class PandasTableApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("PandasTable in Tabs")
        self.geometry("800x600")
 
        # Sample DataFrames
        data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]}
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
        data2 = {'X': [10, 20, 30], 'Y': [40, 50, 60], 'Z': [70, 80, 90]}
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
 
        # Create Tab Control
        tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self)
 
        tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
        tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
 
        tab_control.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
        tab_control.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
 
        tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
 
        # Create PandasTable instances
        self.table1 = Table(tab1, dataframe=df1)
        self.table2 = Table(tab2, dataframe=df2)
 
        self.table1.show()
        self.table2.show()
 
        # Bind events for each table
        self.table1.bind("<Return>", self.handle_return_table1)
        self.table2.bind("<Return>", self.handle_return_table2)
 
    def handle_return_table1(self, event):
        # Custom handler for the Enter key event for table1
        self.table1.handle_arrow_keys(event)
        return "break"
 
    def handle_return_table2(self, event):
        # Custom handler for the Enter key event for table2
        self.table2.handle_arrow_keys(event)
        return "break"
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PandasTableApp()
    app.mainloop()`

this is the error i get:
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:1884: FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version. Call result.infer_objects(copy=False) instead. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)`
  return self.func(*args)
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:1884: FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version. Call result.infer_objects(copy=False) instead. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)`
  return self.func(*args)
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:1884: FutureWarning: Downcasting object dtype arrays on .fillna, .ffill, .bfill is deprecated and will change in a future version. Call result.infer_objects(copy=False) instead. To opt-in to the future behavior, set `pd.set_option('future.no_silent_downcasting', True)`
  return self.func(*args)
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:1884: FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`
  return self.func(*args)
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:1884: FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas. Value '2' has dtype incompatible with int64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
  return self.func(*args)
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\xxxx-xxx\xxx-venv\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.pyy", line 2350, in handle_arrow_keys
    x,y = self.getCanvasPos(self.currentrow, self.currentcol-1)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\xxxx-xxx\xxx-venv\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 2151, in getCanvasPos
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = self.getCellCoords(row,col)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\xxxx-xxx\xxx-venv\lib\site-packages\pandastable\core.py", line 2140, in getCellCoords
    x1=self.col_positions[col]
IndexError: list index out of range

when i write to the 2nd tab it works - im able to write to cell there.
but writing to the firs tab crash and send this error.
any idea why its occured?
thanks in advance.

What do you want to do by passing a Return key event to a function that expects an arrow key event?

It seems the error is related to initialization of the tables in each tab.
I can reproduce the error when trying to modify a cell right after the app is launched on tab1, but if i go to tab2 and then come back to tab1, i get no error.
A workaround could be to manually force initialization by going through each tab after launching the app.
add this line to def __init__(self): :
self.after(100, self.initialize_tabs)

The after method makes sure that the app is loaded. I tried without it and still got the same issue.
And add this method to your class :
def initialize_tabs(self):
    # Switch to each tab to initialize
    self.tab_control.select(self.tab2)
    self.tab_control.select(self.tab1)

Also, you are not handling the return key correctly. The handle_arrow_keys method won't make it for return key.
The pandastable package makes it a bit more complicated to get binds done right.
First we need to store the references to each table in __init__ and bind the return key to the app, not the tables :
self.tables = {self.tab1: self.table1, self.tab2: self.table2}
self.bind("<Return>", self.handle_return)

Then, we can define the handle_return method :
def handle_return(self, event):
    try:
        widget_name = event.widget.rsplit(".!", 1)[0]
        widget = self.nametowidget(widget_name)
        table = self.tables.get(widget, None)
        self.process_enter_key(table)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return "break"

If the return key is pressed when not in a table, nothing will append, but when it is pressed inside a table, the code gets the name of the parent element of the table and then finds the reference to the table with the help of the tables dictionary.
This way, you can manipulate the object as you wish.
For instance :
def process_enter_key(self, table):
    row = table.getSelectedRow()
    col = table.getSelectedColumn()
    if row < len(table.model.df):
        row += 1
    else:
        row = 1
        if col < len(table.model.df.columns) - 1:
            col += 1
        else:
            col = 0
    table.setSelectedRow(row-1)
    table.setSelectedCol(col)
    table.redraw()

This goes to next row if possible. If not, it goes to first row of next column, and if not possible, it goes to first row and first column. This way, you always end up on a cell of the tab when you press the return key.
For a reason I am not aware of, rows are indexed from 1 and column from 0.
